# Javascript Assign text to string

Tags: javascript

i have a text.txt file in which is text like this

```
20x3x11
15x27x5
6x29x7
```

How to assign that to javascript string? When i am doing :

```
var input = "20x3x11
    15x27x5
    6x29x7";

    console.log(input);
```

i am getting in console error - `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Thanks for answers and help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ticks ` for multiline strings.... e.g.

```
var a = ` hi
this 
works`
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can do `"20x3x11\n15x27x5\n6x29x7"`.